# restarting all specific units on systemctl without for loop?

Tags: recursive, systemctl

Is someone here able to start/stop/reload/... a list of units specified with a wildcard or similar method on systemctl?

I try do do somethin like: `systemctl restart openstack-nova-*.services` or `systemctl restart openstack-nova-?.services`

but it's a dead end and I didn't found anything usefull on systemctl's manual.

I could use a for loop but before that I'll have to make a `systemctl -t service --failed` and then grep for listed units... a little bit boring isn't ?

So, if someone know if it's possible to do something like that or not, I'll be happy to hear it.

If it's not, I think I'll push the idea on systemctl developers list or maybe do the patch if I have time to ^^

Comment: What about "systemctl restart openstack-nova*.service" ? Does it work?

Comment: Nop, that what I was talking about on my exemple indeed :(
Thanks for your help!

Comment: What distro do you run?

Comment: I'm running on Fedora 19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soooo, to be noticed for people looking to manage multiple systemd units at same time.
Since 2016 (2017?) Systemd is now accepting wildcard \o/

Exemple:

`systemctl restart openstack-nova-*` is now fully working

PS: At least it works on CentOS 7.x release (That's the only one that I tested).

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE** Systemd supports wildcards from systemd-209 forward https://serverfault.com/a/797926/291826

---

Two years later systemctl still doesn't allow wildcards, even though they would be extremely useful.

I did however take your note about `systemctl -t service --failed` and I hacked together this. I decided to post it here because the next person to find this question could be helped by it.

`systemctl restart $(systemctl -t service --failed | grep openstack-nova-*.service | cut -d ' ' -f 1)`

This takes `systemctl -t service --failed`, greps for the services matching "openstack-nova-*.service" and then removes the descriptors of those files by cutting (`cut`) on the space (`-d ' '`) and taking the first result (`-f 1`). Then it restarts the whole bunch because thankfully systemctl command allows for multiple services to be passed to it to stop.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment in this topic as it's really one of the most annoying missing features of systemctl. I have crafted a similar script myself to be able to perform this kind of operations. Anyway, I'm sure that your post will help a lot of people ;-) thank you very much!!