# On Ubuntu, systemctl (show|status) with wildcards does not work with inactive(dead) processes even with "--all" flag

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, systemctl

Although this https://serverfault.com/a/915634/1060236 suggests all services should be listed, when I run:

`sudo systemctl status "prefix.*" --all` or `sudo systemctl show "prefix.*" --all`

It excludes services where `Active` state is `Inactive (Dead)`. It only shows the services in `Failed` or `Running` state. How can I get the status of the full list?

If I look for status of a `Inactive (Dead)` service directly, then it will show the correct result ie `sudo systemctl status prefix.somedeadprocess.service`:

```
○ prefix.somedeadprocess.service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/prefix.somedeadprocess.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```